# Android post wall facebook dialog missing small icon

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

I have a wierd problem with integrating a basic "post to facebook feed" in my app.
The first time after you install the app and use the post to wall button everything works great.

But after that first run the small icon next to the " via APPNAME" is missing when i use the "post to wall" button, there is just a missing picture questionmark there instead.

Here is the facebook code(tried to keep it simple as i dont require any other facebook functionality in my app):

```
if (facebook == null)
     facebook = new Facebook("<MY_APP_ID>");
//Creating the bumdle parameters with link, picture, name, caption and description
facebook.dialog(this, "feed", parameters, new DialogListener(){});
```

Comment: Tested some more.. 
It works on first login to facebook, and it showes up on the wall when you post it even if it dosent show in the dialog.
But if you are already logged inn to facebook the icon does not show in the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this in the EMU, but actually on facebook the APP ICON actually shows up fine.

I am testing to see if this is a device issue or an EMU issue, but you can rest assured that it posts to FB properly.